# access field data in template.php and create variable for header image in page.tpl.php

Tags: media, theming, entities

I am trying to allow the user to set a custom image to display in the header on node pages that have a header_image field and to display a default header image on all other pages (including system and module generated pages).

I thought I could do this by creating a "Header Image" view and using a contextual filter to get the header_image field on the displayed node. This works okay when displaying a node that has the header_image field but not on a page that doesn't have that field. Because this view is a block the contextual filter uses the default value of "Content ID from URL" and I can't use a fixed default value.

I am guessing I have to use the [preprocess_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) function and [field_has_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_has_data/7) or perhaps the [Entity API Module](http://drupal.org/project/entity) to check if the node has data in the header_image field. If there is no header_image field or it has no value I would like to use the default image for that field. Is there anyway to specify using the default image that was set by the user? other wise I would use the default image at `file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri('public://')->getDirectoryPath().'/default_images/default_header.jpg'`

There must be a common solution to this problem.. Actually I just had a thought.. what if there are multiple nodes on a page? Any suggestions what I should do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently tried to do this but stumbled then over the [Header Image Module](http://drupal.org/project/headerimage) which does this perfectly. It allows you to create a block which holds any content (for example a custom content type) and ads it to a block. You can specify on each content where it should be displayed (nid, path, term etc.).